# Git distributed workflow

Tags: git

We have a "central" git repo containing all sorts of conf files.

We have 5 servers that have the repo cloned.

I've cloned the repo on my local machine.

I want to be able to make changes locally, push to the central repo and then have it automatically push down to the repos on the servers.

Iow, make a change locally, commit, push and the change is visible everywhere else. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the execution of a script that connect to every server and issue a git pull on the post-update [hook](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html) in the central repository.

Or you can simply use cron to do a git pull every 15 minutes on all the servers.